# can one use templated begin/end methods in range based for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, templates

I deal with a class that is meant to be iterable in range based for loops, so it defines an iterator class, begin- and end-method. Now in the example I'm working on, these three are templated (I have this minimal example, where the template parameter isn't really meaningful but just has templated begin and end):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

struct Iterable {
  using Widget = std::tuple<int, float>;
  template <typename access_type>
  struct Iterator {
    Iterable*   m_iterable;
    std::size_t m_pos;
    bool        operator==( const Iterator& other ) { return m_iterable == other.m_iterable && m_pos == other.m_pos; }
    bool        operator!=( const Iterator& other ) { return !( this->operator==( other ) ); }
    access_type operator*() {
      Widget tmp = m_iterable->m_storage[m_pos];
      return std::get<access_type>( tmp );
    }
    Iterator operator++() {
      m_pos++;
      return *this;
    }
  };
  template <typename access_type = int>
  Iterator<access_type> begin() {
    return {this, 0};
  }
  template <typename access_type = int>
  Iterator<access_type> end() {
    return {this, m_storage.size()};
  }
  std::vector<Widget> m_storage;
};
```

Now this iterable works in a range based for loop

```cpp
Iterable container;
for (auto element: container) { … }
```

This uses `begin<int>` and `end<int>` as is somewhat visible from [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=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&insightsOptions=cpp2a&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0) (note the type of the iterator in the range based version of the loop).

What is not clear to me is, is there a way to specify the template parameters for the for loop other than retreating to a pre-c++11 loop?

```cpp
for (auto iter = container.begin<float>(); iter != container.end<float>(); ++iter) { … }
```

EDIT to clarify the scope of the discussion. The iterable class is considered to be preexisting in upstream code, I don't want to discuss the reasons for putting it into the world. Someone else's code just exist and I have to deal with it.

[see also compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/h2gddc)

Comment: why would you do such bogus thing as template `begin` and `end` in first place?

Comment: https://gitlab.cern.ch/lhcb/LHCb/blob/master/Event/TrackEvent/Event/PrZip.h#L258

for SIMD friendly code where the iteration does not go element by element but spits out data in the vector unit's size (i.e. steps of 1/4/8/… elements at a time.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you would need is an adapter that wraps the container and provides the iterators that you want it to have.  That would give you a class like

```
template<typename T>
struct Adapter
{
    Iterable & it;
    Adapter(Iterable& it) : it(it) {}
    auto begin() 
    {
        return it.begin<T>();
    }
    auto end() 
    {
        return it.end<T>();
    }  
};
```

and you would use it like

```
int main()
{
    Iterable container;
    for ( auto element : Adapter<float>{container} ) 
    { 
        static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype( element ), float> );
    }
}
```